# transform: scale3d(1, 0.1, 1); ".1" is too wide

Tags: html, css

The `scale3d()` [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdGyGr) is displaying correctly:

```
label::after {
  z-index: -1;
  background: green;  /* ::after background */
  transform: scale3d(1, .1, 1); /*"Y" should be zero but I put ".1" for now so I can see its initial position" */
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}
```

but [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BOwEdL?editors=0100#0) its not, Why the ".1" is too wide?

Another problem is, If I set to [`transform: scale3d(1, 0, 1);`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RYLOqa?editors=0100#0) and focus on the input field, then nothing happens, I'm hoping to see the green background appear after focus.

Comment: Great! ...so what's your question?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I just set the "Y" to .1 but it display too wide, unlike the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here comes Parent-child relation.
You have directly defined child in **absolute** position without defining the parent. Parent should always have **relative** in position. So let the parent of the child be positioned, so that your **green background** will work correctly

```
.username {position: relative;}
```

Parent is not positioned, so that the absolute property rely on document

Comment: It works, thanks. My problem now is when I focus on input field, the green background doesn't scale down: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxoPdJ.

Comment: .input-field {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
input:focus {
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transition: width 2s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
  z-index: -1;
  background: green;  /* ::after background */
}
you can use the above css